# GWT MVP: Connecting the Dots on Presenters, Activities, Displays & Places

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwt-activities, gwt-places

I am attempting to design my first, super-simple GWT app, that takes advantages of most of GWT's major API features. I think I'm about 70 - 80% of the way there, but after pouring over the GWT docs, countless articles, and posting many other GWT-related questions here on SO, I am still having a tough time understanding the last 20 - 30% needed to put this app altogether.

I have called this first test app `ClickItToWinIt`, and I want it to look like this:

[image]

When the user clicks the "Win" button, a picture ("`win-pic.png`") pops up in the image frame on the left-hand side. When the user clicks the "Lose" button, a picture ("`lose-pic.png`") pops up in the same frame. The user can click back and forth between the buttons to make the different pictures display. This would be a single-page app, hosted locally on my machine, and would only need to contain 1 homepage, 1 module/entrypoint, etc.

**Please note** that the packaging/class structure proposed below is surely overkill for such a simple `ClickItToWinIt` app. However, before long I want to be moving on to bigger and better things with GWT, so it's important to me that I have an understanding of proper GWT coding before I start to tackle bigger apps with more complex UIs.

Also, the proposed structure below is based on 3 GWT principles that Google seems to encourage tirelessly:

- Performance; client-side speed
- Security
- Separation of concerns (MVP, etc.) for ease of testing

One last item here: normally, in my PHP webdev days, I used the concept of "themes/skins" in some of my sites by deploying the site with a different CSS file that simply applied different styling rules to the same DOM elements. Thus I might have a "`normal-styles.css`" file that makes the site look "normal", but also have a "`facebook-styles.css`" file that gives the site the look-and-feel (colors, fonts, etc.) of Facebook, etc. I'd like to accomplish the same thing here and am proposing a `net.bfodder.c2w.client.views.themes` package that will have `AbstractTheme` subclasses in it. These subclasses would somehow be injected/baked into the view/presenter at build-time and would give me a way to deploy the app with a different theme or skin. I *believe* this is the right approach because (if my understanding of `ClientBundle` and `CssResource` is correct) GWT *seems* to have object-ified CSS styles into GWT POJOs. My `AbstractTheme` subclasses would somehow tie into `CssResource` and defined styles for all my `Widget`s.

So here is the proposed `src/main/java` structure of `ClickItToWinIt` (I'm developing in Eclipse 3.7 Indigo with the Google-Eclipse plugin):

```
ClickItToWinIt/
    src/main/java/
        net.bfodder.c2w
            net.bfodder.c2w.client
                MainModule (implements EntryPoint)
                AppController
                ClientFactory
                net.bfodder.c2w.client.views
                    net.bfodder.c2w.client.views.ui
                        WinButton (extends Composite implements ClickHandler; hasA TextButton)
                        LoseButton (extends Composite implements ClickHandler; hasA TextButton)
                        ImageViewer (extends Composite; hasAn Image)
                    net.bfodder.c2w.client.views.containers
                        MainContainer
                        ButtonContainer
                        ImageContainer
                    net.bfodder.c2w.client.views.displays
                        WinActivity (extends AbstractActivity implements AcceptOneWidget)
                        LoseActivity (extends AbstractActivity implements AcceptOneWidget)
                    net.bfodder.c2w.client.views.themes
                        AbstractTheme
                        NormalTheme
                        FacebookTheme --> I really dont't care about FB, just using as an example of a well-known theme/skin
                net.bfodder.c2w.client.presenters
                    IPresenter
                    ButtonPresenter (extends AbstractActivity implements IPresenter)
                    ImagePresenter (extends AbstractActivity implements IPresenter)
                net.bfodder.c2w.client.history
                    InitialPlace (corresponds to http://localhost/clickittowinit)
                    WinPlace (corresponds to http://localhost/clickittowinit/#winning)
                    LosePlace (corresponds to http://localhost/clickittowinit/#losing)
                net.bfodder.c2w.client.events
                    EventBus impl and GwtEvent impls
            net.bfodder.c2w.server
                Not worried about server-side for now; I think I "get" that much!
```

The `AppController` is for any oddball app-level business logic that doesn't belong to any one particular `IPresenter` subclass. The `MainModule` is where everything kicks off (DI, starting preliminary `Activity`, etc.). The buttons get placed inside `ButtonContainer`, the `ImageViewer` gets placed inside the `ImageContainer`, and both those inner containers get placed inside `MainContainer` (which I *assume* is created up in `MainModule`). As far as layout and style of these UI components, like I said this would be up to whatever the injected/configured `AbstractTheme` defines in its rule set.

I'm using the `ClientFactory` as recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces#ClientFactory) for convenient access to major parts of the app's GWT plumbing.

As for the MVP "stuff", here's what I was thinking:

```
public class WinActivity extends AbstractActivity {
    private final ClientFactory clientFactory;
    private final WinPlace place;

    public WinActivity(ClientFactory clientFactory, WinPlace place) {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
        this.place = place;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
        ImagePresenter presenter = clientFactory.getImagePresenter();

        // Inject the presenter with any stateful data here
        // presenter.setImage(getWinImageUri());

        presenter.go(panel);
    }
}
```

#### The Question(s)!

Like I said up above, I *believe* I'm almost there, I'm just having a tough time bridging the gaps on some things. So I ask:

1. How do I wire up my `AbstractTheme` subclasses to use `CssResource` and `ClientBundle` so that my app gets injected/configured with the correct theme, and client browser download the correct CSS file (`normal-style.css` or `facebook-style.css`)?
2. Can someone properly explain the relationship between `IPresenter` (from classic MVP), `AbstractActivity`, "display regions" (`AcceptsOneWidget`) and `Place`s? Is there a 1-to-1-to-1-to1 relation here, or is the intention with GWT to have, say, multiple display regions for every `AbstractActivity`, or some other set of ratios?
3. How do I connect the `WinPlace` with GWT's History API? So if the user clicks `WinButton`, `LoseButton`, `WinButton`, how to have that saved in browser history so they could hit the forward/back browser buttons and recreate this usage pattern over and over again?
4. When the `WinButton` gets clicked, it places a some click event on the Event Bus. Where and how do I wire up a handler/listener to the EventBus that will know: (a) to change the image in the `ImageViewer`, and (b) to store this state change in the History API?
5. I got the idea for the `AppController` from [this article](http://howtogwt.blogspot.com/2010/02/event-handling-and-event-propagation.html), which unfortunately never provides any code snippets for what the `AppController` might actually look like. Can anybody (who is familiar with the `AppController` pattern for GWT) shine some light as to what this would look like? Perhaps its somehow an `IPresenter` subclass with no particular `Activity` or view components?
6. In general, and I **know** that these kinds of "*amidoinitrite?*"-style questions are discouraged on SO, but I have to ask any battle-worn GWT veterans out there: am I way off-base here, or am I more or less on track with GWT best practices? Any suggestions?

I hate to ask such a "super-question" here, but I'd rather do this than clutter SO with 6 medium-sized questions, and just keep repeating the same problem setup over and over again. Plus, with a good code example, it's probably possible to answer all 6 in one fell swoop, so I took a chance here.

Thanks in advance.